# If an account owner of an S3 bucket makes it read only, can this be undone by the same account owner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have one AWS account and multiple IAM users. I have a bucket and at certain times, I want that restricted to read only (I would like to have other users to have to purposely reactivate read & write access). 
If I set my bucket to read only, can this be undone again?

Comment: You can simply remove the write permissions (e.g. s3:Put*) from the IAM policy associated with this group of users and then add it back later when you want to give them write permission again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change bucket and object permissions using a variety of methods including using an ACL, Bucket Policy or individual object permissions.

You can read how to change the ACL of the bucket [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-bucket-permissions.html).

Comment: Note that bucket policies supplement, and in many cases, replace ACL-based access policies so ACL should not typically be your first thought when managing access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it later on and the best way to mange this is using the IAM policy for the user group. If the need occurs to be managed at ACL level then that can be done but not a preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. Nobody has access to the content.

You can grant access in several ways:

- **Access Control Lists (ACLs)** on specific objects, which is good if you want only specific objects to be accessible
- A **Bucket Policy** on a bucket or a portion of a bucket, which is good if you want to grant public access for anything in the bucket or path
- **IAM Policies** that can grant access to specific IAM Users and IAM Groups
- Generating **Pre-Signed URLs** that grant time-limited access to a specific object, which is used by applications to generate authenticated access for specific users

So, there's no actual concept of "setting a bucket to read-only". Instead, you would create a Bucket Policy or an IAM Policy that grants `GetObject` permission to everyone or a specific set of users.

If you wish to change access permissions for a particular time period, you should modify the policy that actually grants the permissions. You will need to do this at the start and at the end of that time period.